# Problema en django y modelos, como iterar o alojar muchos datos de un mismo tipo en un modelo

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo el modelo ventas en django

```
class VentaModel(models.Model):
    productos = models.ForeignKey(ProductModel, related_name="ventas", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

y este tiene como llave foránea otro modelo llamado productos.

Quiero insertar muchos "productos" dentro de una sola "venta" pero hasta el momento solo puedo hacer que se registre 1 solo producto por venta, ademas que no puedo hacer uso de los atributos dentro de productos.

¿Existe una manera de registrar mas de un producto dentro de una sola venta? Pense en utilizar diccionarios o iterar el modelo, pero no se realmente como hacerlo ¿alguna idea? Ademas, ¿Como puedo usar los atributos del segundo modelo en las ventas?
Este es el modelo de productos:

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stockIni = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio = models.FloatField()
```

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el formset en la cual podrías manejar ese problema de tener varios objetos del mismo modelo en una sola parte

Answer (score 1):

Si estas en desarrollo aún y podes cambiar un poco los modelos yo te recomendaría armar los modelos de una forma distinta.

Los productos imagino que deberían existir por su propia cuenta, independientemente de si van a una venta o no, asi que ese modelo no necesita cambiar, salvo el campo cantidad, que si se refiere a la cantidad de un producto que se va a comprar esta vez, no debería ir ahí porque no serviría para distintas ventas.

La venta podría tener la fecha de la venta, el total, y algún campo más, como quien la hizo.

Y lo más importante es que deberías hacer un modelo mas que relacione producto con venta, algo como ProductoDeLaVenta, que tenga una foreign key al producto, la cantidad que se compra y otra foreign key a la venta.

Estoy asumiendo algunas cosas sin saber de que va el programa que estas haciendo, pero yo lo haría mas o menos así

```
class ProductoDeLaVenta(models.Model):
    venta = models.ForeignKey(VentaModel)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(ProductModel)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()


class VentaModel(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

De esta forma, a partir de una venta se pueden pedir todos los productos.

```
ProductosDeLaVenta.objects.filter(venta=TuInstanciaDeVenta)
```

O con el related name creo que también.

Espero haber sido de ayuda!